# How to create executable jar with standalone HSQLDB in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hsqldb, executable-jar

I have a java project in Eclipse with the following structure:

```
MyProjectFolder
  |
  ├─ src
  ├─ data
  ├─ lib
```

In this project I'm using HSQLDB in standalone mode. The database files are stored in the data folder, and I'm accessing them by using this URL when making the connection:

```
"jdbc:hsqldb:file:./data/" + dbname
```

Everything works fine when executing the project in Eclipse. Now I'm trying to export the project into a runnable jar, and it is failing to connect to the database. I have tried to add the data folder to the list of sources in Eclipse, and also to add the folder manually to the jar, or even putting the data folder outside the project folder and changing the url accordingly, but nothing have worked ¿Is it possible to achieve that using a jar?¿ or should I deploy the application using another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to connect to a database within a jar file, you have to use `jdbc:hsqldb:res:` instead of `jdbc:hsqldb:file:`. But if you want to write to the database and this is not possible within a jar file, I probably would place a default database within the jar and if no database is found at a defined place outside of the jar, the program copies the default database to the defined place and then connects to the database.

Is it correct, that you cannot connect to the database outside of the jar file? If so, please explain your directory structure and the whole URL to the database.